# strange behaviour with readlink under cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, readlink

I'm trying to use readlink -f to get the absolute path to a shared library following all symlinks.

```
>readlink -f /opt/gcc4.9.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/gcc4.9.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
```

but when I do this in cmake it doesn't expand the full path
E.g.

`set(CPP11_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/)
execute_process(COMMAND ldd ${CPP11_PATH} COMMAND grep libstdc++ COMMAND awk "{ print $3; }" OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_PATH)
message("LIBSTDCPP_PATH=${LIBSTDCPP_PATH}")
execute_process(COMMAND readlink -f ${LIBSTDCPP_PATH} OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH)
message("LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH=${LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH}")`

prints:

```
LIBSTDCPP_PATH=/opt/gcc4.9.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH=/opt/gcc4.9.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

This also happens if I wrap it in a shell script:

`execute_process(COMMAND doreadlink.sh ${LIBSTDCPP_PATH} OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH2)
message("LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH2=${LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH2}")`

```
>LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH2=/opt/gcc4.9.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

It also happens using get_filename_component() with REALPATH which ought to be the canonical cmake way to do this.

`get_filename_component(LIBSTDCPP_PATH ${LIBSTDCPP_PATH} REALPATH)
message("LIBSTDCPP_PATH2=${LIBSTDCPP_PATH}")`

Can anyone explain?

I have tried both cmake rebuild_cache and removing the CMakeCache.txt and running with --trace to ensure what I think is being run is really being run.
I've also confirmed it happens on rhel5 rhel6 & rhel7 and with both cmake 2.8 & 3.4.

There is a workaround that behaves correctly:

`execute_process(COMMAND ldd ${CPP11_PATH} COMMAND grep libstdc++ COMMAND awk "{ print $3; COMMAND xargs readlink -f }" OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_PATH)`

What might cmake be doing under the hood?

I tried running:

`strace -f cmake pwd`

some of the output is:

```
[pid 23195] execve("/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/readlink", ["readlink", "-f", "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6\n"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] execve("/usr/local/bin/readlink", ["readlink", "-f", "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6\n"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] execve("/usr/bin/readlink", ["readlink", "-f", "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6\n"], [/* 53 vars */] 
[pid 23174]  "", 1)   = 0
[pid 23195]  )      = 0
[pid 23174] close(11)                   = 0
[pid 23174] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  
[pid 23195] brk(0 
[pid 23174]  NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 23195]  )         = 0x12e5000
[pid 23174] read(9, "", 1024)           = 0
[pid 23174] close(9)                    = 0
[pid 23195] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 
[pid 23174] close(6)                    = 0
[pid 23195]  )        = 0x7ff41654f000
[pid 23174] close(8)                    = 0
[pid 23195] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK 
[pid 23174] select(8, [3 5 7], NULL, NULL, NULL 
[pid 23195]  )      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] stat("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff36038350) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] stat("/usr/local/lib/tls", 0x7fff36038350) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

*snip*

```
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] stat("/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/tls", 0x7fff36038350) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] stat("/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff36038350) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23195] open("/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT TERM CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH=/usr/lib64/lib"..., 45LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

) = 45
```

So it even looks like its executing the right system command.

Here is a CMakeLists.txt to reproduce the problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TEST CXX) 

set(CPP11_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cpp11)
execute_process(COMMAND g++ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp11.cpp -o${CPP11_PATH})

#execute_process(COMMAND ldd ${CPP11_PATH} COMMAND grep libstdc++ COMMAND awk "{ print $3; }" COMMAND xargs readlink -f OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_PATH)
execute_process(COMMAND ldd ${CPP11_PATH} COMMAND grep libstdc++ COMMAND awk "{ print $3; }" OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_PATH)
message("LIBSTDCPP_PATH=${LIBSTDCPP_PATH}")
execute_process(COMMAND readlink -f ${LIBSTDCPP_PATH} OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH)
message("LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH=${LIBSTDCPP_ABSPATH}")
```

Comment: Within `strace` output it is shown, that you pass **newline-terminated path** to the `readlink`: "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6\n". Probably, this is a reason of difference with direct `readlink` invocation.

Comment: I think you are close to nailing it there. A \n doesn't seem to do it but a trailing space does. So the question becomes where are the trailing characters coming from?

Comment: If you are a reputation point chaser you can add an answer and I'll accept it otherwise I will accept my own. Thanks for the tip either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many shell utilities which output *single line* terminates it with newline (`\n`). This is done for pretty output in the terminal.

Unlike to *backtricks operator* (`exec-some-command`) in Linux shell, which automatically strips trailing newline, `execute_process` doesn't do this by default.

The simplest way to strip trailing newline within `execute_process` output is to use `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` option for it:

```
execute_process(COMMAND <...>
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBSTDCPP_PATH
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tsyvarev has nailed it. The problem is a trailing newline caused by my awk output.
If I change it from:

`awk "print $3"`

to:

`awk "printf($3)"`

All works as expected. Hurrah!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way. Please use

```
“execute_process(COMMAND readlink -fn ${SYMLINK_PATH} OUTPUT_VARIABLE FILE_PATH)
```

-n or —-no-newline means “don’t output the trailing newline.”